# Bash,Postfix, AWK, Error in filtering deferred mail output

Tags: awk

This is what I have tried so far:

`cat /var/spool/postfix/deferred/D3B921090 | awk -F"/"  '{print $6}'  |awk '{$1="" print $0}' | sort | uniq -c | sort  -n`

and

`awk -F"/"  '{print $6}' < /var/spool/postfix/deferred/D3B921090 | awk '{$1="" print $0}' | sort | uniq -c | sort  -n`

I get the following error message when trying to run either command:

```
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near print
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '{$1="" print $0}'
```

is not a syntactically valid expression, did you mean

```
awk '{$1=""; print $0}'
```

which is equal to

```
awk '{$1=""}1'
```

?